# Why are ‘much’ and ‘high’ used differently?

Tags: word-usage

‘Much’ and ‘high’ both mean ‘a large amount’ but why are they used differently? For examples ‘much temperature’ means several temperatures whether they are cold or not, but ‘high temperature’ means hot temperature.[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to ELL. Please take a look at both words in a learner's dictionary, for example: www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com and https://www.macmillandictionary.com You may also wish to look up "English grammar quantifier" and "English grammar intensifier". The dictionary pages will give the meanings, examples, and some information about how and when they are used. If you still have questions, please edit your question here to ask for details. Also look up *many*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Much* is used with quantifiable things. "We don't have much sugar" works because sugar is a substance, and we can measure how much of it we have. Temperature is not itself a thing you can have more or less of. It is a measurement, an inherent physical property that every object has. The temperature is always there. It can be a high temperature or a low temperature, but things don't have *more* or *less* temperature than others. (By contrast, something can have more or less *heat*.)

Comment: But ‘temperature’ has a plural form. Doesn’t it mean temperature can be quantifiable?

Comment: It has a plural form because different objects can have different temperatures. But none of them have _more_ or _less_ of a temperature than the others. They all have temperatures, because temperature is an inherent physical property of an object. Their temperatures can be higher or lower, though. I can see how this can be confusing, especially when comparing with other measurements like _weight_ (something _can_ have _more weight_).

Comment: It’s off-topic but why not high weight?

Comment: @user2483 _High weight_ also works, but it's less common since we have a dedicated word for this: something with a high weight is _heavy_. (Something with a high temperature is of course _hot_.)